# Why catch statement doesn't catch the error?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exception

For some reason the catch statement doesn't catch the error in my project.

I have created a mini project to reproduce the error: It has two activities and it switches between them with `startActivity()` and `finish()` respectively.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static int counter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            System.out.println(counter);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        if (counter++ < 100) {
            try {
                System.out.println(counter);
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Although everything is surrounded in try-catch statements and I'm aiming to catch the highest type possible it doesn't catch it.

This is the stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 22538
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Activity client record must not be null to execute transaction item: TopResumedActivityChangeItem{onTop=true}
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.getActivityClientRecord(ActivityTransactionItem.java:66)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:43)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2308)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Any idea of why this can't be caught and how to avoid the crash?

Not the original question but any general idea of how to fix this crash (so it won't need to be caught in the first place) will also be helpful, as I couldn't find any solution that worked. The error happens on a specific device I used for the Android Studio emulator: 'Nexus 6' with API 33. I didn't encounter this issue in the few other devices I used in the emulator. The error eccurs usually around the 50'th time `startActivity()` is called, but it seems completely random somewhere between 1 and 100 calls.

Comment: As you can see, your `MainActivity` methods aren't even mentioned in the stack trace. So the exception is thrown in another thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the code you have inside the try blocks doesn't truly throw exceptions that can be caught, the try-catch blocks in your program are unlikely to capture any exceptions.

There is no checked exception that the Android startActivity function throws that you can catch using a try-catch block. It may instead throw runtime exceptions, such as ActivityNotFoundException or SecurityException, which are not have to be explicitly caught.

You can take the following actions to deal with exceptions that arise when initiating an activity:

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // Handle the case where the activity is not found
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    // Handle the security exception
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle any other exceptions
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, it's usually preferable to design your code so that control flow is not dependent on catching exceptions. Instead, before invoking the method, you can use conditional statements to look for circumstances that could cause an exception. Your code becomes more resilient and comprehensible as a result.

In your particular situation, you can use an if statement to check the condition before calling startActivity if you wish to prevent initiating the SecondActivity when a specific condition is satisfied.